# Show dimensions in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've started trying the autodesk-forge samples and I would like to customize how elements show up on the viewer.
So my question is: Is it possible to show the plan elements' dimensions (as shown in the picture below) with Autodesk-viewer?
I can see this dimensions if I click on an element, but I'm trying to get something like this when the viewer starts:

[image: Plan with dimensions]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to create dimensions at the moment, but you can use custom implementation to add Three.js lines like the dimension command is doing. You can basically add any 2D/3D custom graphic element to the viewer scene.
[image]

Unfortunately we have no sample that illustrates how to achieve that, you may take a look at the code of the Measure Extension, see line#60358 in [viewer3D.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=3.2.1), but there is quite a bit of work to achieve...

Hope that helps.

Comment: just appending some more info for your reference @atuq, one Forge customer has implemented something like adding dimensions to Forge Viewer: https://vimeo.com/user59752895 . It proved the workflow Philippe mentioned.